# Cycles Special Passes - Artefacts in Multipass Compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes

Hello my dears blender artists!

I think you know there is too low numbers of quality tutorials about Cycles special passes:

- z depth
- Vector/speed
- UV
- obj/mat index
- and manually generated World position or Point volume position pass
- normal pass

These Cycles extra passes are not optimized on high end standard. It cannot be used in compositing without artefacts.

Could you make some professional tutorial or course on some complex scene where we could see how to solve these issues?

For example:

- z depth VS speed blur in composite (what to apply first? how to solve dancing edges when we use z depth pass on beauty pass? We want physically correct blurs of that kinds like in render with that blur which is slower...)
- UV pass - remapping object with complex topology and UVWs
  as everybody knows - index luma passes are not optimized - we always have anti aliasing dancing edges in any compositing software
  I know for new criptomatte pass , but how to solve these...
- point position pass: we cannot have it as the others passes - we have to do render again in mode: "material to override all other".
  Yes, yes I saw it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEerSx19ydU
  but that is out of date solution - when we use this manually created pass - for example Fusion, Nuke, After, Blender cannot read it correctly like Vray or Octane point position pass.
  https://youtu.be/kwzbO38q_fQ?t=197
  Usage of this technique is something amazing and powerful
- Normal pass for example to apply in relighting scene or part of scene?

Of course, all of these artefacts we cannot see when we do compositing on single frame, but big part of blender community has these problems in composited animation.

Cycles multipass rendering is not better in last blender verions, the problem is the same as in 2.50, 2.60 and in 2.70 generations!

I would like to buy this tutorial or course as many others members
or at least to support you in some platforms like Patreon...

Comment: Have a look at number 1 in the list : https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tutorial requests are considered off topic on this platform.

Comment: Hi Jovica! That's the wrong place to ask for a tutorial. This is a *Q&A site*, see the [help page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help). Better ask at *blenderartists.org* or even better: just ask a *question* and add what you've tried so far.

Comment: I think it would get answered well quickly on blenderartists.org, that's a good advice.